# Converting DTO to model. How to get values fromTupleConverter$TupleBackedMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, tuples

Hi I'm trying to get specific values from a jpa repo class. By creating a interface class and appending with get methods. But I couldn't get values from it.

I can see the values in debug mode. But without the key.

But while trying to access it, I'm getting null in return.

Bellow is the code flow.

**Controller Class**

```
public class DocumentFileSearchController 
{
    @Autowired
    DocumentDetailService documentDetailService;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/getDetails")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getdocDetail(@RequestParam(value = "sourceCaseId") String sourceCaseId,
                                          @RequestParam(value = "mdmId") String mdmId,
                                          @RequestParam(value = "sourceSystem") String sourceSystem) throws MissingServletRequestParameterException
    {
        List<DocumentDetailsResponceModel> modal = documentDetailService.getUsingSourceAndMdm(sourceSystem, mdmId);
         
        return new ResponseEntity<>(modal, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Service Interface Class

```
public interface DocumentDetailService 
{
    
    public List<DocumentDetailsResponceModel> getUsingSourceAndMdm(String sourceSystem, String mdmId);

}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class DocumentDetailServiceImpl implements DocumentDetailService
{
    
    @Autowired
    private DocumentDetailRepo docDetailRepo;
    
    List<DocumentDetailsResponceModel> docResponceModel;

    public List<DocumentDetailsResponceModel> getUsingSourceAndMdm(String source, String mdmId)
    {
        docResponceModel = docDetailRepo.findBySourceCaseMdm(source, mdmId);
                    
        return docResponceModel;
    }
}
```

I can see the values inside.

[image]

Should I use any tupleImpl for this? Because those values are under this. But I'm not familiar with this.

But getting null in response.

[image]

Repo Class

```
public interface DocumentDetailRepo extends JpaRepository<DmsDmDocumentDetail, Long> 
{   
    @Query("select d.documentId, d.fileName, d.mdmId, d.sourceCaseId, d.sourceSystem, d.individualId from DmsDmDocumentDetail d where d.sourceSystem = :sourceSystem and d.mdmId = :mdmId")
    public List<DocumentDetailsResponceModel> findBySourceCaseMdm(@Param("sourceSystem") String sourceSystem, @Param("mdmId") String mdmId);

}
```

I tried by setting this way in query.

```
@Query("select new com.hhs.document.model.DocumentDetailsResponceModel(d.documentId, d.fileName, d.mdmId, d.sourceCaseId, d.sourceSystem, d.individualId) from DmsDmDocumentDetail d where d.sourceSystem = :sourceSystem and d.mdmId = :mdmId")
public List<DocumentDetailsResponceModel> findBySourceCaseMdm(@Param("sourceSystem") String sourceSystem, @Param("mdmId") String mdmId);
```

But getting the error
`An Error Occured : Could not determine appropriate instantiation strategy - no matching constructor found and one or more arguments did not define alias for bean-injection`

DTO class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "dm_document_detail", schema = "dms")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DmsDmDocumentDetail 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "document_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long documentId;

    @Column(name = "active_ind")
    private String activeIndicator;

    @Column(name = "create_dt")
//    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date createDt;

    @Column(name = "create_user_id")
    private String createUserId;

    @Column(name = "doc_cat")
    private String docCat;

    @Column(name = "doc_type")
    private String docType;

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;
    
    @Column(name = "file_location")
    private String fileLocation;
    
    @Column(name = "user_file_name")
    private String userFileName;

    @Column(name = "individual_id")
    private int individualId;

    @Column(name = "source_system")
    private String sourceSystem;

    @Column(name = "source_case_id")
    private String sourceCaseId;

    @Column(name = "update_dt")
//  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updateDt;

    @Column(name = "update_user_id")
    private String updateUserId;
    
    @Column(name = "screen_lable_id")
    private int screenLableId;
    
    @Column(name = "mdm_id")
    private String mdmId;
}
```

Model class to get particular column values.

```
public interface DocumentDetailsResponceModel 
{       
    Long getDocumentId();
    String getFileName();
    String getMdmId();
    String getSourceCaseId();
    String getSourceSystem();
    Integer getIndividualId();
}
```

Thanks E>